# SQL query: group and count distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, distinct

Given this DB table:

```
A_column       B_column
---------------
A1      1
A1      2
A1      2

A2      1
A2      1
A2      1

A3      2
A3      3
A3      4
A3      5
```

How do I write SQL SELECT query to print out number of unique values in B_column per value in A_column, so output would be like this:

```
A1     2
A2     1
A3     4
```

I tried this, but doesn't seem to work properly:

```
SELECT A_column, count(B_column) FROM table GROUP BY A_column
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct`:

```
SELECT A_column, count(distinct B_column) FROM table GROUP BY A_column
```